# success function is not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I developed an application and in which i am inserting some records by using the service.
The data is successfully inserted but the problem is my success function is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BtnRegister').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "DataService.svc/InsertData",
                data: '{ "Name": "' + $("#TxtUserName").val() + '", "Email" : "' + $("#TxtUserEmail").val() + '", "Category" : "' + $("#TxtUserCategory").val() + '", "Mobile" : "' + $("#TxtUserMobile").val() + '", "Message" : "' + $("#message").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("data");
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('Loading Failed...'); }
            });
        });
    });
```

There is an alert message generated after inserting the data which generates from the error function. The data in inserted successfully. The error function is running every condition.

My InsertData Method:

```
public string InsertData(string Name, string Email, string Category, string Mobile, string Message)
    {
        string file = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\DataFile.xml";             

        DataTable dtUser = ReadXML(file);

        DataRow dr = dtUser.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = Name;
        dr["Email"] = Email;
        dr["Category"] = Category;
        dr["Mobile"] = Mobile;
        dr["Message"] = Message;
        dtUser.Rows.Add(dr);
        dtUser.WriteXml(file);            
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean the `error` handler runs every time instead?

Comment: _The data in inserted successfully._...if this is the case then alert should come. May be you need to stop your form to submit i think.

Comment: Have you confirmed it's not running your error function? With the alert content commented out, you might not know it's running the error instead. Even if the service is running successfully and inserting the data, you might end up in the error function if it isn't returning a positive HTTP response code. In your browser, try running IE F12 tools, Firebug or the debugger of your choice to analyse the network when this AJAX call is made and see what HTTP response code you're getting back.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes..

Comment: if the error handler runs, the problem is in your external script

Comment: see what firebug return data

Comment: @myfunkyside how do i change the code in external script?

Comment: @sakir there is no error is coming in the firebug

Comment: open the external script in an editor, the `DataService.svc`. I assume you have that at your disposal?

Comment: how   error: function (result) { run then ???1

Comment: what is the result your getting in the error handler?

Comment: Or it could also be that the external script doesn't contain an error, but the data send to the script is wrong in some way. Wrong format or something, but that's very hard for us to determine with the information we have here

Comment: Although, this `"Name": "' + $("#TxtUserName").val() + '",` could just as well, maybe even should, be this: `"Name": ' + $("#TxtUserName").val() + ',` (`$("#TxtUserName").val()` doesn't need quotes I believe)

Comment: And should `"Name"` and all the other be quoted at all? Those are properties of an object right? See [**this link**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp), then they don't need quotes

Comment: @myfunkyside by using this the data is not inserting.

Comment: @myfunkyside after using the above jquery code, the loading failed alert message is generated

Comment: @sakir by using the above jQuery code, the error function is running on every condition

Comment: you should retun string in u  function

Comment: @sakir i have used it, sorry it not copied. i am returning the "success"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BtnRegister').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",              
                url: "DataService.svc/InsertData",
                data: '{ "Name": "' + $("#TxtUserName").val() + '", "Email" : "' + $("#TxtUserEmail").val() + '", "Category" : "' + $("#TxtUserCategory").val() + '", "Mobile" : "' + $("#TxtUserMobile").val() + '", "Message" : "' + $("#message").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {   console.log('Loading Failed...'); }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have used your code. but the error function is running on every condition.

Comment: @NimitJoshi, please post your "InsertData" method.

Comment: The data is inserted successfully but the error function alert message running.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BtnRegister').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",              
                url: "DataService.svc/InsertData",
                data: '{ "Name": "' + $("#TxtUserName").val() + '", "Email" : "' + $("#TxtUserEmail").val() + '", "Category" : "' + $("#TxtUserCategory").val() + '", "Mobile" : "' + $("#TxtUserMobile").val() + '", "Message" : "' + $("#message").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {   console.log('Loading Failed...'); }
            });
        });
    });
```

Try this, I added `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax call. By the way, what data type are you returning after the ajax process was done?

Comment: what data type is being returned by method this "DataService.svc/InsertData"?

Comment: try replacing dataType: 'json' to dataType: 'text'